# Modify or create user with custom OnPremisesSecurityIdentifier in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, azure-active-directory

We are trying to create users with `OnPremisesSecurityIdentifier` attribute but without AD Connect. I mean by using Azure api, Microsoft api or PowerShell
Since now we couldn't do it because it is an only read attribute.
But then, if it is only readable, it means that only AD Connect can set it?

Since now we have tried `New-AzureADUser` and `Set-MsolUser` in PowerShell, and use it api graph: Microsoft and Azure. But none of them make the magic.

[Here is pretty clear that is not writable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0), but AD Connect can do it, so there has to be a way...

Comment: Why do you want to set it manually? This will be returned by default if you use AADC.

Comment: Hi, Tony. Thanks for the answer. We are trying to manage all of our identities from one source wich is going to create users on any other repository, in order to get control of any of them without AD Connect. If we use AADC then we lose control over AAD users. I mean, they would be identities created from one place that is not our one and unique source. Besides, it is a requierement from our client, so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have confirmed this with Azure support team. There is no way to set `OnPremisesSecurityIdentifier` attribute by ourselves. This will be returned by default when you use Azure AD Connect.

Hope it helps.

Comment: It hopes a lot!! Thank you for the answer Tony. It would be good to be able to set that attribute, but at least we know for sure that it is impossible.